# How to join a table in typeORM with innerJoinAndSelect service

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Entity -pin

```js
@Entity()
export class Pin {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({name: 'town_name'})
  townName: string;

  @Column()
  state_id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => State, state => state.stateId)
  state: State;
}
```

Entity -state

```js
@Entity()
export class State {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: 'state_id'})
  @PrimaryColumn()
  stateId: string;

  @Column({name: 'state_name'})
  stateName: string;

}
```

Service:

```js
const pin = pinRepository.createQueryBuilder('pin').leftJoinAndSelect('pin.state','state').getQuery();
    console.log(pin);
```

I'm new with nest and typeORM and try to join the two table. but it's returning wrong query:

```sql
SELECT "pin"."id" AS "pin_id","pin"."town_name" AS "pin_town_name", "pin"."state_id" AS "pin_state_id", "pin"."stateStateId" AS "pin_stateStateId", "state"."stateId" AS "state_stateId", "state"."state_name" AS "state_state_name" FROM "pin" "pin" LEFT JOIN "state" "state" ON "state"."stateId"="pin"."stateStateId"
```

While I would want something queries like this:

```sql
select id, town_name, Pin.state_id, state_name from Pin inner join State ON Pin.state_id = State.state_id
```

In which part that I've passed the wrong thing? or is there any way I can overcome this problem.

Comment: What is wrong in the query? That it is `left join` instead of `inner join`?

Comment: there was no column "pin"."stateStateId", it's should be take from state.stateName

Comment: what should be taken from stateName? you have stateId as primary column on state. I posted an answer, please review and comment if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what are the issues you're struggling with but the following should work.
I think the problem is in the entities relation definition.

Take a look at [@JoinColumn](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md#joincolumn-options)

```
// pin.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Pin {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({name: 'town_name'})
  townName: string;

  @Column()
  state_id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => State, state => state.pins)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'state_id' })
  state: State;
}
```

```
// state.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class State {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: 'state_id'})
  stateId: string;

  @Column({name: 'state_name'})
  stateName: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Pin, pin => pin.state)
  pins: Pin[]

}
```

Also, change left to inner join.

```
const pin = await pinRepository.createQueryBuilder('pin')
.innerJoinAndSelect('pin.state','state')
.getMany()
```